# Suggestions for choosing an automation QA package?

Tags: user-interface, scripting

What QA package offers the widest possible support and is the easiest/fastest to develop for?  The qualities I am looking for are:

- widest support of scripting languages, or which language your preferred package supports
- capability to test webpages for interaction against forms and user interfaces
- capability to test data input for qualitative/quantitative analysis against definitions you provide
- is fastest to write definitions for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is currently gaining some popularity and supports several languages (1). In addition, the [robot framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) makes for a nice way to run selenium and non-selenium based tests.

(1)  java, groovy, ruby, C#, perl, PHP, python as of this writing